# SQL Server - Show All possible Values and Count Them

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have the following table:

```
IdSce Year NoIte Value
1     0    1     1 
1     0    2     5
1     0    3     1
1     1    1     2 
1     1    2     3
1     1    3     2
2     0    1     4     
2     0    2     4
2     0    3     1
2     1    1     2 
2     1    2     4
2     1    3     3
```

I want to group by IdSce and Year, and show each possible value and count how many time each value appears like this:

```
IdSce Year Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5
1     0    2       0       0       0       1 
1     1    0       2       1       0       0
2     0    1       0       0       2       0
2     1    0       1       1       1       0
```

Thanks !

**EDIT**

shawnt00 is really close to what I want, but I'm looking to do it as dynamic as possible, meaning if I have 10 different values for the column *value*, I will be missing information in my table. Therefore, if I have 10 different values, I want 10 new columns (value1, value2, ... , value10)

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT  IdSce 
        ,Year
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 0 and Value < 1 THEN 1 else 0 end) Zero
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 1 and Value < 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) One
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 2 and Value < 3 THEN 1 else 0 end) Two   
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 3 and Value < 4 THEN 1 else 0 end) Three
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 4 and Value < 5 THEN 1 else 0 end) Four
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 5 THEN 1 else 0 end) FiveMore
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN Value >= 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) Total  
FROM    Table
GROUP BY    IdSce
            ,Year
```

Thanks for the help again!

Comment: Solved many times on here. Either use `pivot` or `count(case when "Value" = 1 then 1 end) as "1", ...`

Comment: @shawnt00 .. you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Why do you need to transform the data to be across in SQL?  Can't the UI do that for you?  If so a simple aggregate would work!  If you have to do it dynamically then you have to use DYNAMIC SQL.  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: @xQbert Nope, it has to be exported to Excel after, and if I don't find a way to diminish the number of rows, I'm going to have millions of rows since Year and Iteration are usually from 0 to 99

Comment: So... export to excel and then pivot in excel... ok if i'ts really millions of rows maybe excel can't handle the volume so I can see why you may have to pivot before excel...  but I don't know many people who look at millions of rows in a file either...

Comment: You could certainly preaggregate the values prior to pivoting. That should reduce the number of rows substantially if that's a major hurdle in your approach. At the same time there are column limits in Excel too.

Comment: @shawnt00 That could work, I group by IdSce, Year and Value, and add a new column Count(*) to count how many times each value occurs. That way, I reduce the number of rows and can finish the analysis in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll do it!

```
select IdSce, "Year"
    count(case when Value = 1 then 1 end) as "1",
    count(case when Value = 2 then 1 end) as "2",
    count(case when Value = 3 then 1 end) as "3",
    count(case when Value = 4 then 1 end) as "4",
    count(case when Value = 5 then 1 end) as "5"
from T
group by IdSce, "Year"
```

I think you'll often find this filed under "conditional aggregation". SQL Server has a proprietary syntax that uses `pivot` if you want to look into that also.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answering, I tried that, but thing is I want to do it as dynamic as possible.

I want it to show ALL values possible and count how many there are, so if there are 10 different values, I want 10 new columns.

I'll add the edit.

Comment: Dynamic pivot generally involves dynamic sql unless you use other tools. You'll find solutions to that problem as well with those keywords.